# Why does it matter if my EC2 instance is publicly available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I have three allowable inbound requests on my Linux EC2 instance.

```
Type                  Protocol      Port Range        Source
SSH                   TCP           22                [my ip address]
Custom TCP Rule       TCP           8787              0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule       TCP           3838              0.0.0.0/0
```

The first is my IP address and the other two are for RStudio Server. My understanding is that, even though it is set for RStudio Server, anyone can make inbound requests since the source is open.

Nobody can access my EC2 instance without the private key file, which is safe and secure.

Given that, why does it matter whether my EC2 instance is private?

Answer (score 2):

The private key file is to authenticate you for an ssh session (or to retrieve the password for a Windows EC2 instance).

If a port is accessible to the public, and an application is listening on that port someone may be able to exploit a vulnerability in that application and compromise your EC2 instance.

Even if only the ssh port is open to public but no one other than you has the private key, it's possible (theoretically) for someone to brute force ssh (although not practically possible).